# mysqli to postgres database

Tags: php, database, postgresql, mysqli

I create a script to insert data from a mysqli database to a postgres database

```
<?php
      $conn = new mysqli(...........);
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection fialed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }
      else
      {
      echo "MySQL connection successfull\n";
      }
      $db = pg_connect(.................);
      if(!$db){
      echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
      } else {
      echo "PostgreSQL connection successfull\n";
       }
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM crm_subscriptions";
      echo $sql . "\n";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      echo $conn->error . "\n";
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $psql = "
        INSERT INTO subscriptions_sub (id,cust_id,tarrif_id,des,datetime_created,datetime_modified,credit,credit_limit,status,date_start,date_end,backoffice_userref,backoffice_deleted,backoffice_createdon,backoffice_createdby, backoffice_updatedon,backoffice_updatedby,backoffice_administration,backoffice_readonly,backoffice_order,backoffice_dummy)
        VALUES('" .(int) $row["subscription_id"] . "','" . (int) $row["customer_id"] . "','" . (int) $row["tariffplan_id"] . "','" . $row["description"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["datetime_created"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,NULLIF('" . $row["datetime_modified"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["credit"] . "','" . (int) $row["credit_limit"] . "','" . $row["status"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["date_start"] . "','')::timestamp,NULLIF('" . $row["date_end"] . "','')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["backoffice_userref"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_deleted"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["backoffice_createdon"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["backoffice_createdby"] . "',NULLIF('" . $row["backoffice_updatedon"] . "','0000-00-00 00:00:00')::timestamp,'" . (int) $row["backoffice_updatedby"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_administration"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_readonly"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_order"] . "','" . (int) $row["backoffice_dummy"] . "');
        ";
        print_r($row);      
        $ret = pg_query($db, $psql);
        if(!$ret){
            echo pg_last_error($db);
        } else {
            echo "Records created succesfully\n";
        }       
        }
        } else {
    echo "0 results \n";
      }
       ?>
```

When I run it I get this error:

> invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "" in
>   /home/ruud/Database2.php on line 38
>  ERROR: invalid input syntax
>   for type timestamp: ""root@149-210-204-94:/home/ruud#
>  ERROR: 
>   invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""Array

**datetime_created and datetime_modified are from type TIMESTAMP date_start and date_end are from type DATE backoffice_createon and backoffice_update** on are from type DATETIME

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a postgres driver/module, as mysqli is the driver for mysql.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Or if the package is installed, you need to enable de module in php.ini

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll (windows)
extension=php_pgsql.so (linux)
```

you may already have it installed. check your `phpinfo();`

Comment: I have edited my php.ini and executed phpinfo(); but I cant find any interesting in phpinfo. Where do I need to look for?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a dedicated tool to migrate data from mysql to postgres. MySql has dates like 00-00-0000 which do not exist and will be rejected by Postgres. A tool like PgLoader can handle such cases.